# BitmapFrame to BitmapImage conversion?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I convert a BitmapFrame to a BitmapImage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a [PngBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.pngbitmapencoder.aspx) [or one of this other encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to save the `BitmapFrame` to disk and then load it from disk to create your `BitmapImage`.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/dee0e287-b345-4e01-888a-ecfb9c3f40b0